# File append race condition (single thread!)

Tags: linux, file, append, race-condition

My program does something like:

- Open a file (append mode)
- Write some stuff
- Close
  [repeat]

The file is different most of the time but on certain occasions (not uncommon really) is repeated (either consecutively or in a very close iteration).
Is there any chance kernel can play tricks on me and opening the file not pointing to the end of the file? Say the write is not yet completed (buffered somewhere in the kernel) and opening the file again makes the fd point to a position that is not the real end of the file. That will result potentially in overlapping writes.
As I said, my program is single threaded, I see no reason why this would happen but I do not fully understand the kernel guarantees when it comes to this.

Thanks!

Comment: You *really* need to provide a [mcve] for this. There are lots of different ways you can potentially get surprising outputs (mixing buffered and unbuffered write calls would do it, for example), but addressing *any* of them requires having some actual details to speak to.

Comment: Buffering that's pertinent for non-power-loss scenarios is mostly done at the C library layer (or otherwise language-runtime), not the kernel. This makes a question that doesn't specify your implementation language, or (better!) the specific calls in use, exceptionally useless.

Comment: Also, the filesystem matters: If you're on NFS, for example, then real POSIX semantics for `O_APPEND` may not be available. On a compliant filesystem, *all* writes with `O_APPEND` are guaranteed to go straight to the end, no matter what... but not all filesystems are fully compliant. So, again: Details matter, and they need to be included in the question.

Comment: I'm literally using an ofstream object in a function (that's called from a loop). The object is destroyed every time before being instantiated again for the next file. The file is opened in append mode and written to it via << operator. Is that enough?

Comment: Hmm. An ofstream's destructor should flush, but I don't know C++ well enough to know if the point in time when it actually does so is well-defined (gave the language up in disgust back in the egcs days, when it was not unheard of to have three subsequent compiler point releases having three different defensibly standards-compliant behaviors). I'd suggest using `sysdig` or such -- that way you can get a timeline of when the actual write syscalls fire, factoring buffering within the C++ standard library out of the question.

Comment: (Suggesting sysdig rather than strace to make that trace sufficiently unobtrusive from a performance perspective as to reduce the chance that the act of observing is likely to change the outcome)

Comment: What about fopen/fclose? And regular open/close? I want to know what the spec says about this

Comment: Which spec? `fopen` and `fclose` aren't syscalls, so they aren't anything that's specified at a kernel level at all. The `close()` syscall *is* specified, and guaranteed, to flush content to be visible to other processes (not necessarily living on disk to survive a reboot) before completing.

Comment: It sounds like you should have a question tagged to be about your language runtime, *not* about the Linux kernel... but even then, I'm still calling this effectively unanswerable without a [mcve] that lets someone else reproduce the issue (and, by extension, specifies your issue sufficient to allow a 100%-certain understanding of exactly what the corner case you're asking about actually *is*).

Comment: ...because as I said before -- right now *we can't possibly tell* if you have an issue caused by a misinterpretation of language runtime guarantees, an issue caused by use of a noncompliant filesystem, an issue caused by a genuine bug in some layer or another. There are simply too many layers involved for it to be reasonable for an answer that goes into which guarantees are and aren't offered (both in practice and by-spec) for all possible code that meets the extremely vague English-prose process description in this question.